# Web scraper/CSV not saved in the correct form

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

The web scraper that i have made works fine. But the csv file does not have the right configuration. I assume something is wrong with the placement of `csv_writer.writerow([])` or the whole `for`statment is wrong? 
I would like to get it written like : `"header","source","text"`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import csv


source = requests.get('http://trenertadej.si/pocep-je-osnovna-vaja-za-noge/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')

csv_file = open('novi.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['header','source','text'])#column names,headers to my csv file 

div = soup.find('div',class_="fusion-column-wrapper")# to je iskalno polje kjer iščem vse elemente...



try:
    for h in soup.find_all('h2'):
        header = h.text
        print(header)
        print()
        #exit()
        #csv_writer.writerow([header])
except Exception as e:
    p = None



try:
    for img_source in soup.find('div',class_="fusion-column-wrapper").find_all('img'):
            source = img_source['src']
            print(source)
            #exit()
            #csv_writer.writerow([source])
except Exception as e:
        p = None


try:
    for p in soup.find_all('p'):
        text = p.text
        print(text)
        #exit()
        #csv_writer.writerow([text])
except Exception as e:
    p = None


csv_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csvwriter.writerow()` method, as the name suggests, is supposed to write a row of values. What you are trying to do here (I'm assuming) is to write all the values for each column separately. I would suggest to completely refactor your code into small functions, where you parse the data first, store it into an appropriate data structure (a list of lists where each lists represents the values for each row should be sufficient) and then print it to csv.